# Java. Проблемы с получением текущей даты в ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java, ubuntu, дата

Добрый день! Написал тут программу, которая должна считать кол-во дней до какой-то даты. Столкнулся с тем, что не совсем корректно работают методы получения текущей даты. Может, это как то связано с тем, что у меня линукс на компе. Вот код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
    // write your code here
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        Date date = dateFormat.parse("29.03.2018");
        long range = getDateRange(currentDate, date);
        System.out.println(range);
    }
    public static long getDateRange(Date d1, Date d2){
        long a = d2.getTime()-d1.getTime();
        return a/(1000*60*60*24);
    }
```

Помогите разобраться в проблеме, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что вы получаете и что ожидали?

Comment: `mm` - это минуты, правильный формат будет `dd.MM.yyyy`

Comment: Спасибо, счас попробую

Comment: Все работает, еще раз спасибо